# Python PyPDF - EOF Marker Not Found

Tags: pypdf

I have seen other articles that talked about doing something along the lines of:

```
fileOpen = file(file_name,'a')
fileOpen.write("%%EOF")
file.close()
```

But this does not work For me. Anyone have any clue why that's the case? I've been searching on this site and others, but have yet to come up with an answer. I am using Python btw in Backtrack Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who's curious, I just had forgotten that pyPDF only supported PDF files, and this is why it generated this error when I tried getting the metadata from other files. Stupid part on my end.